# MySQL truncating text while loading data into table

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, loaddata

I've tried to load sentences from CSV file that seems to have tab delimited columns.
But as I can see there are some problem, sentences are loaded cut off and hase ellipsis (...) at the end. In the CVS there are longer.

[image]

[image]

I am using standard LOAD DATA

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "sentences.csv" INTO TABLE sentences CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
```

for sentence column I've used both TEXT and VARCHAR(15000)
it is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` COLLATION

For example I have such sentence

```
11026408    eng The Stevens family, however, continued to work at the subject, and by 1841 had determined by actual experiment the thickness of wrought-iron armour which was proof against the projectiles then in use.
```

loaded as `The Stevens family, however, continued to work at ...`

Comment: I don't think it's truncating the data, it is just displaying it in the truncated form. On hovering, it should display the complete text.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is phpmyadming issue. When I've queried data from Terminal it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Ok as @Charchit Kappor well pointed out it is issue with displaying data in phpmyadmin. But this data are still completely stored in database and can be queried from Terminal.

mysql> SELECT sentence FROM sentences WHERE id = 11026408;

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sentence                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| The Stevens family, however, continued to work at the subject, and by 1841 had determined by actual experiment the thickness of wrought-iron armour which was proof against the projectiles then in use. |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (3.67 sec)
```